# Align a molecule with notation including (+) in a scheme reaction in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I am doing the scheme shown in the first image.
[image]
[image]
Second image shows the scheme done by the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig[atom sep=1.6em]{C(-(*6(=-=-=-)))(-[4](*6(-=-=-=)))(=[6]O)}
\arrow(a--){->[$h\nu$]}
 \chemleft[
  \chemfig[atom sep=1.6em]{C(-(*6(=-=-=-)))(-[4](*6(-=-=-=)))(=[6]O)}
 \chemright]
\arrow(a--){->[RH]}
\chemfig[atom sep=1.6em]{\charge{45=\.}{C}(-(*6(=-=-=-)))(-[4](*6(-=-=-=)))(-[6]OH)}
\arrow{0}[,0]
 \+ \charge{45=\.}{R}
\arrow(@a.north east--){0}[,0] $*$
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

When I add the command \chemname in order to add "initiating radical" to the last product (third image), the plus sign and the R radical moves up. I'd like to keep the + sign and the radical aligned with the arrow and the legend below the radical. I'd also like to add a wider gap between the + and the R radical. Any suggestions?

This is my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig[atom sep=1.6em]{C(-(*6(=-=-=-)))(-[4](*6(-=-=-=)))(=[6]O)}
\arrow(a--){->[$h\nu$]}
 \chemleft[
  \chemfig[atom sep=1.6em]{C(-(*6(=-=-=-)))(-[4](*6(-=-=-=)))(=[6]O)}
 \chemright]
\arrow(a--){->[RH]}
\chemfig[atom sep=1.6em]{\charge{45=\.}{C}(-(*6(=-=-=-)))(-[4](*6(-=-=-=)))(-[6]OH)}
\arrow{0}[,0]
 \+ \charge{45=\.}{R}
\arrow(@a.north east--){0}[,0] $*$
\schemestop
\\
\schemestart
\chemfig[atom sep=1.6em]{C(-(*6(=-=-=-)))(-[4](*6(-=-=-=)))(=[6]O)}
\arrow(a--){->[$h\nu$]}
 \chemleft[
  \chemfig[atom sep=1.6em]{C(-(*6(=-=-=-)))(-[4](*6(-=-=-=)))(=[6]O)}
 \chemright]
 \arrow(a--){->[RH]}
\chemfig[atom sep=1.6em]{\charge{45=\.}{C}(-(*6(=-=-=-)))(-[4](*6(-=-=-=)))(-[6]OH)}
\arrow{0}[,0]
 \+ \chemname{\charge{45=\.}{R}}{initiating\\radical}
\arrow(@a.north east--){0}[,0] $*$
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is a solution for you. I added `\arrow(--[yshift=-13pt]){0}[,0]` in front of chemname so you can shift the R along the y axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    %\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig[atom sep=1.6em]{C(-(*6(=-=-=-)))(-[4](*6(-=-=-=)))(=[6]O)}
    \arrow(a--){->[$h\nu$]}
    \chemleft[
    \chemfig[atom sep=1.6em]{C(-(*6(=-=-=-)))(-[4](*6(-=-=-=)))(=[6]O)}
    \chemright]
    \arrow(a--){->[RH]}
    \chemfig[atom sep=1.6em]{\charge{45=\.}{C}(-(*6(=-=-=-)))(-[4](*6(-=-=-=)))(-[6]OH)}
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+ \charge{45=\.}{R}
    \arrow(@a.north east--){0}[,0] $*$
    \schemestop
    \\
    \schemestart
    \chemfig[atom sep=1.6em]{C(-(*6(=-=-=-)))(-[4](*6(-=-=-=)))(=[6]O)}
    \arrow(a--){->[$h\nu$]}
    \chemleft[
    \chemfig[atom sep=1.6em]{C(-(*6(=-=-=-)))(-[4](*6(-=-=-=)))(=[6]O)}
    \chemright]
    \arrow(a--){->[RH]}
    \chemfig[atom sep=1.6em]{\charge{45=\.}{C}(-(*6(=-=-=-)))(-[4](*6(-=-=-=)))(-[6]OH)}
    \arrow{0}[,0] \+
    \arrow(--[yshift=-12pt]){0}[,0]\chemname{\charge{45=\.}{R}}{initiating\\radical}
    \arrow(@a.north east--){0}[,0] $*$
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A different approach: `\charge{45=\.,270:20pt={\begin{tabular}{c}initiating\\radical\end{tabular}}}{R}`